# React: ReactDOM.render() does not render anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React for the first time and I am having trouble getting this simple thing to work.

What I need to do is to add an h1 element to the div with id 'app' but nothing is showing on my browser page. No errors on both the server-side and client-side consoles. Before I wrapped ReactDOM.render() in an if statement, the following error occurred:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I would like to do this without using JSX since the lesson does not cover this until later.

app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Clock extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement('h1', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
    }
}

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Clock, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log(React);
    console.log(ReactDOM);
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How are you interacting with these files, precisely? The error you mentioned – `document is not defined` – doesn't make sense with a browser loading the page. However, it could occur if you're running `app.js` elsewhere, such as with Node.js, as most other environments don't automatically include a DOM implementation.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I am running app.js using nodemon. I read somewhere that the if statement is supposed to dismiss the error, and it did, but nothing is showing in my browser.

Comment: `nodemon` isn't capable on its own of preparing files for your browser. It's meant to monitor and restart scripts written for Node.js, especially those that define a server application listening for requests. – Since you're already loading React and ReactDOM via `<script>`, you don't need the `require()` calls in `app.js`. And, without them, the page can load `app.js` with just another `<script>`. – If you'd rather keep each `require()`, then you'll need to start using a build tool, such as Webpack, to prepare `app.js` for a browser to understand.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I just tried deleting the require calls and added the script tag with app.js as the src, but now I am getting errors on both the server and client side. Server-side: `ReferenceError: React is not defined` and client side: `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: I guess there's a problem with your setup , just copied your code and tested seems working fine check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xkgard

Comment: I tried making it from scratch with another set up, and was able to get it to work. Thank you both for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a different setup as the two commenters suggested, and it indeed fixed the issue. I found the following and it worked:
[Github - Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

To create new project (mac terminal):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```